# What is the proper schema type for a personal portfolio

Tags: schema.org

I recently completed my personal portfolio that includes links to other web sites that I have designed and developed. I'm not sure what the proper schema type is here.

[Creative Work](https://schema.org/CreativeWork) was my first instinct 
but this seems like it might be better geared towards an individual creative work, not a collection of them like is featured on my website. For example one of the websites I created was for an author to sell his book, and this *clearly* falls under this schema.

[Person](https://schema.org/Person) could also work but seems pretty generic.

Am I just overthinking this and really could choose either one of these and be fine? Ultimately I would like my website to show above my social media when people google my full name and I'm hoping that this will help.

Comment: "an individual creative work, not a collection": With "collection", do you mean your page listing a collection of creative works you worked on, or do you mean that one of your works (e.g., a website) consists of multiple works (e.g., multiple pages)?

Comment: My portfolio is a single page website with a section dedicated towards screen shots with links to the sites that I've built for clients.

Comment: But for which entity do you think `CreativeWork` is not suitable because it”s a "collection"?

Comment: My own website since it's main focus is to show off the websites I've built.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You typically need multiple different entities for representing everything in structured data.

You are a [`Person`](http://schema.org/Person).

The page where you list your works could be a [`CollectionPage`](http://schema.org/CollectionPage). You could specify the `Person` as [`author`](http://schema.org/author) (and any other applicable property, like [`publisher`](http://schema.org/publisher) etc.).

Every work which you created would be a [`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork), but typically a more specific type, of course (like [`WebSite`](http://schema.org/WebSite)). Again, you list the `Person` item as `author` or whichever property is applicable. (In case of website development, it seems to be problematic to differentiate between the author of the site (i.e., the development) and the author of the content.)

To connect the `CollectionPage` and each created `CreativeWork`, you could either use the [`hasPart`](http://schema.org/hasPart) property, or you could add an [`ItemList`](http://schema.org/ItemList) via [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity).

---

That said, this structured data doesn’t necessarily lead to any user-visible feature in Google Search. For those user-visible search features, Google lists in their documentation which types and properties are required.