# Alternatives for CollectionPage

Tags: schema.org

#### Context

Suppose I have a `WebPage` which gives a lot of semantically marked-up information about a specific collection of things. These things could adequately be identified by the type `CreativeWork`.

On the same page these CreativeWorks are displayed.

Intuitively I would use http://bib.schema.org/Collection for the information section about the collection (and use the the `hasPart` property to refer to its items), because the definition of `Collection` is:

> A created collection of Creative Works or other artefacts.

See: http://bib.schema.org/Collection

However, bib.schema.org says it is an extension of schema.org, which

> defines terms such as Audiobook, Thesis, ComicStory, and
>   workTranslation

This seems limiting the use of bib.schema.org to collections with textual or spoken content.

I doubt if a `CollectionPage` is a good choice in this case, because the webpage document does not  *solely* lists collections, but also gives a lot of semantically marked-up information about a the collection itself.

#### Question

Which type should I use for the collection itself? Are there alternatives for `CollectionPage` which do not identify a page, but rather a section of it?

---

See also [this link](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104786/what-is-the-proper-schema-type-for-a-personal-portfolio/), which I found useful while searching for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think that you need an alternative.

You have three levels (the page, the collection, the items), and all of the three corresponding types you mention would be the best choice.

#### `CollectionPage`

It’s perfectly fine (and I would guess it’s even the most common case) that a [`CollectionPage`](http://schema.org/CollectionPage) contains content about the collection in addition to the collection items.

[`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage) conveys "Here is a web page", while [`ItemPage`](http://schema.org/ItemPage) conveys "Here is a web page about a single thing", and [`CollectionPage`](http://schema.org/CollectionPage) conveys "Here is a web page about a group of things".

Of course one could argue that the collection itself is the single thing an `ItemPage` could be about, but that would make the `CollectionPage` type pointless. `ItemPage` for a collection could make sense if you only provide content about the collection, but no collection items.

#### `Collection`

It doesn’t really matter what an extension’s overall purpose is. The only thing that matters is what each single type means.

The [`Collection`](http://bib.schema.org/Collection) type is defined to be for collections of "Creative Works or other artefacts". If it would only be intended for textual or spoken content, it would have been defined as such. (But it’s likely that it would have been renamed then, because Schema.org tries not to use general terms for types which can’t be used according to the meaning of that term. There can only be one type named `Collection`, because the core vocabulary and all extensions share the same namespace.)

So if you have a collection of `CreativeWork` items, it’s perfectly fine to use `Collection`.

If `Collection` is not appropriate for your case, you could use `ItemList` instead. Or you could directly use `hasPart` on `CollectionPage` (i.e., omitting the second level).

#### Example

The structure with all three levels could look like this (in RDFa):

```html
<body typeof="schema:CollectionPage">

  <!-- content about the collection page -->
  <time property="schema:dateModified">2017-11-22</time>

  <!-- the collection -->
  <div property="schema:mainEntity" typeof="schema:Collection">

    <!-- content about the collection -->
    <div property="schema:description">…</div>

    <!-- the collection items -->
    <div property="schema:hasPart" typeof="schema:CreativeWork"></div>
    <div property="schema:hasPart" typeof="schema:CreativeWork"></div>
    <div property="schema:hasPart" typeof="schema:CreativeWork"></div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Perfect answer @unor, exactly the kind of information I was looking for.